# How to remove &raquo; before each title?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using a custom title for homepage and other pages, but I have `&raquo;` before each title except the homepage, Any idea how to remove it?

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

My header code is:

```html
<?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
             bloginfo('name'); ?> &raquo; <?php bloginfo('description');
          } elseif ( is_front_page()){
            bloginfo('name'); ?> &raquo; <?php bloginfo('description');
          } elseif ( is_home()){
            bloginfo('name'); ?> &raquo; <?php bloginfo('description');
          } else {
            wp_title(); ?> &raquo; <?php bloginfo('name');
          }
?>
```

As well I have tried the following loop, but still same error

```html
<?php
          if (is_front_page() ) {
            bloginfo('name'); ?> &raquo; <?php bloginfo('description');
          } else {
            wp_title(); ?> &raquo; <?php bloginfo('name');
          }
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove it just from homepage or all pages?

Comment: Can you please have a look at provided screenshot which can describe very well.

Comment: I've seen the screenshot but still not very clear on what you need to do. Are you trying to remove it from homepage only, all page but the homepage, or all pages all together?

Comment: brother if you can see in screenshot, there is and extra symbol before the title i want to remove it before the title

Comment: @Sheedo He mean `»` before _Performance_.

Comment: Oh! We might be looking at the wrong code then. Can you provide the code that's between `<title> </title>`. You might find it in your index.php or header.php.

Comment: I deleted my answer now that I understand the question better. But I still believe we're looking at the wrong code. Thanks @Sami

Comment: @AhmadBhatti Put it in your question please, not here.

Comment: That's already in my question, the first one

Comment: I don't see it anymore, were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: Yes Brother i already resolved the issue, please check my answer......Thank's alot for your precious time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have found the solution

Error Line:

```html
wp_title(); ?> &raquo; <?php bloginfo('name');
```

Replaced with:

```html
wp_title('&raquo;', true, 'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name');
```

Final Code:

```html
<?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
             bloginfo('name'); ?> &raquo; <?php bloginfo('description');
          } elseif ( is_front_page()){
            bloginfo('name'); ?> &raquo; <?php bloginfo('description');
          } elseif ( is_home()){
            bloginfo('name'); ?> &raquo; <?php bloginfo('description');
          } else {
            wp_title('&raquo;', true, 'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name');
          }
          ?>
```

Comment: Nice code, but you didn't remove it. All you did was move it to the right. This is one of those small quirks of WordPress that should never exist in the first place. Let's go to the Open Source and remove that double carat so nobody else has to waste time on Stack Overflow searching for a simple solution to remove a HTML special character from the title.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to directly edit the **header.php** file and replace the `wp_title();` with `wp_title('');`. It worked in my case (I coded my own theme), hope it works for you as well.